# logstash-forwarder diagnostic and testing

Tags: logstash

Is there any way to test connectivity, using logstash, to see if my shipper server can connect to the logstash server?

I can send events via the same machine/localhost, and the events are making it into logstash and eventually elasticsearch.

I just need a quick and dirty command line to test sending events.

Comment: It doesn't precisely answer your question, but 'telnet' will test the general connectivity and help you rule out network/firewall problems.

Comment: Yes telnet has been working. I guess I am stumped at logstash-forwarder.

Comment: I definetely cannot ssh from one linux box to another. but the telnet does work.

Comment: If you can telnet from the shipper to the port that logstash is listening on, then your network is OK.  logstash-forwarder requires certs, and newer versions require the SANs information in the certs.

Comment: I guess that could be my problem. I'm trying to run without the certs. Im on a amazon vpc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple script that will write an event to a dedicated file, sleep for a few seconds and then query the elasticsearch database for that exact event. If the event was written to the database you can output and OK message and if not an Error message.